# AutoLayout - button outside margins and are too large

Tags: xcode, swift, uibutton, autolayout, constraints

I am creating a memory match app and I cannot get my buttons in auto layout to work properly. After hours of trying the buttons are not shrinking and stay outside the screen. Do any of you have a clue on how to fix this.
[image: This is my Xcode Project Picture]

Comment: Could you add a description of how you laid out the buttons' constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work using Stack View. let me walk you through it:

[image: working layout]

First, you group a row of buttons then you go to Editor -> Embed In -> Stack View

Then you apply the following settings:

[image: horizontal stack view]

After you repeat that for all the rows, select all the horizontal stacks and make them into one stack View by again going to Editor -> Embed In -> Stack View. and make it look like this:
[image: Vertical Stack]

since it appears that you care about the spacing between squares, make sure to select all squares and apply the aspect ratio constraint to them.

just to be clear, your constraints should look like this:

[image: Vertical Stack Constraints]

then each horizontal stack should look like this:

[image: horizontal stack constraints]

Here is a link to the project for you to further explore:
[project Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kq5cjmyh938npnr/buttonLayout.zip?dl=0)

Comment: But how do i add this to my current project from the file you linked? @Unis Barakat

Comment: I would recommend clearing all constraints in your project and basically doing them over by following the steps outlined above.

Comment: @JOHNRIVERS it shouldn't take long. would take like 3 minutes max to do it for all of them. Let me know if anything is still not clear and I would be glad to help you.

Comment: @JOHNRIVERS if your question has been answered, please accept the answer. thanks :)